# How to Change Membase Memory Quota?

Tags: membase

I have two Membase servers running with 1GB memory each. In the future, I want to replace them with two 8GB-memory servers. Is this possible with Membase? From the search I have made, I have the impression that once the memory quota is set, it can no longer be changed. If it is possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually changed in 1.6.4, it used to not be possible, now the cluster will accept this command: [Configuring a cluster's memory quota](http://wiki.membase.org/display/membase/Membase+Management+REST+API#MembaseManagementRESTAPI-Configuringacluster%27smemoryquota)

Comment: I clicked the link but the page is empty. Do you have any other link I can use?

Comment: http://techzone.couchbase.com/wiki/display/membase/Membase+Management+REST+API#MembaseManagementRESTAPI-Configuringacluster%27smemoryquota

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`couchbase-cli cluster-init -c host:portnumber -u user -p password --cluster-init-ramsize=1024`

Where host is your address, portnumber the port for your couchbase server, user is de administrator username and password the one you configured when you installed membase.

1024 is the amount of memory in MB.

Answer (score 0):

The command is

> curl -d memoryQuota=400
>   http://localhost:8091/pools/default

Link to the wikipedia page Perry is referring to is [here](http://techzone.couchbase.com/wiki/display/membase/Membase+Management+REST+API#MembaseManagementRESTAPI-Configuringacluster%27smemoryquota)